# Gnuplot: how to add y2 axis scale for different units

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting data from a file. The data points are in metric units. I want to show a second scale on the right (y2) that's in standard units.

The file represents rocket motor thrust over time. The data are in Newtons. I want to show newtons on the left (this happens by itself, naturally) and pounds force on the right. The conversion is a simple factor (multiply N by 0.2248 to obtain lbf).

I can set y2tics and if I set y2range manually, they appear on the right. What I don't know how to do is set y2range automatically to y1range * a factor.

My eventual solution is to plot twice, once in Newtons on y1 and once in pounds on y2, and make the y2 plot almost invisible:

```
plot '-' using 1:($2*0.2248) with dots axes x1y2 lc rgb 'white' notitle, \
      '' using 1:2 with lines lc rgb '<color>' title '<title>'
```

---

The solution above often generates slightly different y scales: with autoragne, gnuplot rounds up the range so the top tick on each axis is a round number, and of course the rounding is different for different units.

Ultimately I end up with Python code that finds the highest thrust value in each graph, then I explicitly set yrange to that number and y2range to that number * 0.2248:

```
f.write("set yrange [0:%s]; set y2range[0:%s]\n" % (peak_thrust, peak_thrust*NEWTON_LBF));
```

Here's the end result: http://www.lib.aero/hosted/motors/cesaroni_12-15-12.html (sample graph below)
[image]

Comment: Good information.  Thank you from November 2017.  However, I see you say "with dots" and I do not see any dots.  Also, can you show what your datafile looks like?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems to me that the easiest way to do this is to simply scale the data:

```
set y2tics
plot sin(x) w lines, 5*sin(x) w lines axes x1y2
```

Of course, you're plotting data from a file, so it would look something more like:

```
set y2tics
FACTOR=0.2248  #conversion factor from newtons to lbf
plot 'datafile' u 1:2 w lines, '' u 1:(FACTOR*$2) w lines
```

If you're setting the yrange explicitly (which you may need to do):

```
set yrange [ymin:ymax]
set y2range [ymin*FACTOR:ymax*FACTOR]
```

---

Finally, if you really want to rely on autoscaling, you're going to need to do some "gymnastics".

First, set a dummy terminal so we can `plot` without making a plot:

```
set term unknown
plot 'datafile' u 1:2  #collect information on our data
```

Now that we've collected information on the data, we can set our real `y2range`

```
FACTOR=0.2248
set y2range [FACTOR*GPVAL_Y_MIN : FACTOR*GPVAL_Y_MAX]
set y2tics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
```

Now set the terminal and plot the data:

```
set term ...
set output ...
plot 'datafile' u 1:2 w lines
```

Comment: So what it comes down to is that I need to plot the data twice, once on each y axis?

Comment: @iter -- I guess not really.  (see my updated code).  If you set the y2range explicitly, you can get around that.

Comment: Every code snippet I see above plots twice (except the one that sets range explicitly, which I don't want to do; I'm relying on autoscale). The last snippet plots twice also, it just throws the first plot away (to the fake terminal)

Comment: @iter -- Yes, that's true.  You need to read the data twice.  Once to set the scale if you're autoscaling.  Is performance really that big of an issue for this script?

Comment: What I ended up doing is sort of like your second approach, but with explicit axes and make the first plot almost invisible:

Comment: plot '-' using 1:($2*0.2248) with dots axes x1y2 lc rgb 'white' notitle, '' using 1:2 with lines lc rgb '<color>' title '<title>'

Comment: Another option (which may or may not work, I don't have time to try it right now) is make the first plot with the `unknown` terminal, but tag the data as `volatile`.  Then after re-setting the terminal, you could use `refresh` instead.

Comment: @iter -- That's basically my first suggestion.  But, there's no reason to believe (a-priori) that gnuplot will scale the y2 axis exactly the same as the y axis.  This can be proved by:  `plot exp(x) w l, 5*exp(x) w l axes x1y2`.  You'll see that the two plot traces don't sit exactly on top of each other.

Comment: If I use visible colors on both plots, they seem to come out on top of each other. Thank you for pointing out that they don't have to. Interestingly, your exp(x) plots comes out a lot closer to each other if I set y2tics; set ytics nomirror

Answer (score 19):

Version 5.0 added support for this kind of relations between the `y` and `y2` (or also `x` and `x2`) axis:

```
set xrange[0:370]
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics
set link y2 via 0.2248*y inverse y/0.2248
plot x
```

[image: example for <code>set link</code>]

Comment: I cannot get this to work if both the y and y2 axes are logarithmic :( There is a discussion [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1736/)

Comment: @vagoberto Sorry, cannot help you there. I guess it simply doesn't work. I tried to combine linking of y and y2 with `set nonlinear` (newly added to CVS), but you cannot combine those.

Comment: Thank you for this information.  Directly working with `set link y2=something in terms of Y` is excellent for simple conversions like Deg F on one side and Deg C on the other.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question and the answer has already been accepted, but I think it's worth sharing my approach.

I simply use modified labels for the x2axis. In your case, this would be

```
set y2tics ("10" 10/0.2248, "20" 20/0.2248 etc etc...
```

that can be looped this way

```
do for [i=0:1000:10] { set y2tics add (sprintf("%i",i) i/0.2248) }
```

where the `for` range should be adjusted according to your data (you could use `stats` and the variable `GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX` for complete peace of mind).
Don't forget to

```
set ytics nomirror
```

This will give exactly what are you looking for, in (almost) a one liner:
[image]

If you want to use a grid and have the converted factors on the `x2axis`, so that for example to the label y=50 N would correspond y2=11.2 (it keeps things tidy if you use a grid) you can do

```
do for [i=0:1000:50] { set y2tics add (sprintf("%5.1f",i*0.2248) }
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: Well worth adding.  Thank you.