# Gnuplot : second X axis related to the first one

Tags: gnuplot, axis

Imagine I have three columns in a data file and I want to plot say column 1 versus column 2 having a second X-axis being related to the first one.
I have been trying to use something like this :

```
set x2tics 0.2
set xtics nomirror
set xrange[0:1] reverse
plot 'output.txt' u 2:($14*1e5):x2tic(100) w l lw 3 title '{/Symbol W} wrt X_c', '' u ($1*1e-7):($14*1e5) w l lw 3 axes x2y1 title '{/Symbol W} wrt t'
```

This gives me two plots : 1vs2 and 1vs3. I'd like to plot 1vs2 and just having the second X-axis giving the time associated with each point : at each point, I want the second X-axis to give me the value of the 3rd column associated with the 1st X-axis (column 1).

[image]

I'm sorry if it's not clear..
Thanks for your help.

Edit : I use gnuplot 4.6 & the relation between the two X-axes is not linear

Comment: Since both scales in your figure are linear and as far as I understood you want to use both axes to refer to the same set of points, I suppose that the relationship between the columns `($1*1e-7)` and `2` in your data has to be linear as well?

Comment: With gnuplot 5 you could use `set link`, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26737333/2604213 or http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/linkedaxes.html for examples

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is the relation between columns ($1*1e-7) and 2 is NOT linear, otherwise there would be no problem I guess.
I do not use gnuplot 5 sadly, but I may upgrade if really needed