# Gnuplotting CPU Load and %CPU

Tags: gnuplot

I have awk-extracted top -b output into a file giving lines like

```
16:23:36 2.58 190.9 7.0
```

(time, load, %CPU, %MEM)

Is there an easy way to plot load and cpu (and mem) into one diagram so that both y values are spread over the whole vertical diagram range?

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969531/gnuplot-how-to-add-y2-axis-scale-for-different-units) suggests scaling the data, but is it possible to have the scaling of the y ranges automatically done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include your plot command so we can help you better.

Look into using both y-axis. Add `axis x1y1` to one of your data items in the plot command and add `axis x1y2` to the other.

Each y-axis will now self scale to fit the data unless you issued a `yrange` command.

Comment: also add `set tics nomirror; set y2tics` so that the two y axes have distinct tic marks and labels